# Is there a PHP library equivalent to cURL that does not need to be installed?

Tags: php, proxy, curl

I am trying to proxy through php for a JS RSS feed. The company I am doing this for may or may not want cURL installed. If that is the case I may need some sort of library that can simply be included in php rather than go through apache and all of that. Is there a library that can handle something like that? What other options do I have in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zend_HTTP](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) provides a wrapper for fopen, file_get_contents and CURL out of the box, it makes it much more simpler to store / read cookies, make POST requests and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`wget`, `fopen`, and `file_get_contents` are other options you can use to use for a proxy.

Comment: file_get_contents is an easier way to use fopen, but, yes, that is an option.

Comment: @CodeJoust: file_get_contents is not the same as using fopen. "file_get_contents() is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance."